# Cannot find cosf in msvcr100.dll using GetProcAddress

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I am learning myself to load DLL files at run time and call functions from there.
For a start, I decided to pick mathematical `cosf` function. After some searching I learned that all mathematical functions can be found in `msvcr100.dll`. So here is code that I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

FARPROC getEntry(HMODULE &m, const char* name) {
    FARPROC p=GetProcAddress(m, name);
    if (!p) {
        printf("Error: Entry %s not found\n", name);
        printf("Error code: %d\n",GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    } else
        printf("Entry %s loaded\n", name);
    return p;
}

int main() {
    HMODULE msvcr = LoadLibraryA("msvcr100.dll");
    if (!msvcr)
        printf("File msvcr100.dll not found\n");
    else
        printf("msvcr100.dll loaded\n");
    FARPROC fun = getEntry(msvcr, "cos");
    FARPROC fun2 = getEntry(msvcr, "cosf");
    FreeLibrary(msvcr);
    return 0;
}
```

If I run it, I get the following output:

```
msvcr100.dll loaded
Entry cos loaded
Error: Entry cosf not found
Error code: 127
```

Why?

- Error code 127 stand for `ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND` -- The specified procedure could not be found.
- According to Dependency Walker, there is a `cosf` function inside MSVCR100.DLL. Ordinal number 1349, Entry Point 0xC2750.
- The function name does not seem to be mangled.
- Both 'cos' and 'cosf' are listed in the run-time library function reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydcbat90.aspx

What am I missing?
If I should use a different dll for `cosf` -- which one is it?
`cos` takes doubles, I need a function which takes floats.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `<math.h>` header file:

```
inline float cosf(_In_ float _X)
        {return ((float)cos((double)_X)); }
```

Or in other words, it is an inline function that actually uses cos().  And thus isn't exported from the DLL.

Comment: Ow... I didn't check the contents of the header file. But if that is so, why does this function appear by the Dependency Walker? It should not exist at all in DLL, or ... ?

Comment: Dumpbin.exe /exports, I don't see it.  There is a ___libm_sse2_cosf export, I don't know what it does.

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't tried Dumpbin, I thought the Dependency Walker shows the same thing. But now when I tried, I see there is a significant difference between those two. Thank you!